# What is the most efficient way to apply CSS to a list without changing every single list on the page?

Tags: html, css

Complete HTML/CSS newbie here. This question came to me when I was editing HTML and tried to change a specific list to display as `inline` but did not want to affect every other list on the page.

I created a class to separate the list in question, the HTML/CSS is below:

```css
li.shortcut {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p>To navigate faster click on these shortcuts.</p>
    <ul>
      <li class="shortcut"><a href="#header1">Shortcut 1</a></li>
      <li class="shortcut"><a href="#header2">Shortcut 2</a></li>
      <li class="shortcut"><a href="#header3">Shortcut 3</a></li>
      <li class="shortcut"><a href="#header4">Shortcut 4</a></li>
      <li class="shortcut"><a href="#header5">Shortcut 5</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Is there a more efficient way to achieve the same thing? I am following a book but it is slowly becoming outdated so I am wondering what would be the current standard way of writing this if it already isn't.

Comment: If you want all `<li>` elements to be affected, then you could apply a single CSS class to the `<ul>` element instead.

Answer (score 2):

When you want specific changes to children, think `id` or `class` on the *parent*.

```
 ul.menu li { display:inline; ... }
```

and

```
<ul class=menu><li>...</li>...</ul>
```

Answer (score -2):

try use `CSS :nth-child() Selector` like this

```css
li.shortcut:nth-child(2) {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<p>To navigate faster click on these shortcuts.</p>
    <ul>
      <li class="shortcut"><a href="#header1">Shortcut 1</a></li>
      <li class="shortcut"><a href="#header2">Shortcut 2</a></li>
      <li class="shortcut"><a href="#header3">Shortcut 3</a></li>
      <li class="shortcut"><a href="#header4">Shortcut 4</a></li>
      <li class="shortcut"><a href="#header5">Shortcut 5</a></li>
    </ul>
```

or use another way you want [source](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: This is the opposite of what they're asking for. They want to style *every* li element.

Comment: oh i am sorry i just read on this part "change a specific list"